# Concatenating functions in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to create an utility object/function `size`, which given a dom element `myDom` and calling another function as `big` or `small` change the inline style of `myDom`.

Currently I am interesting in a solution for actually passing `myDom` to function `big` or `small` so there the inline style modification can happen.

I would like to know which JS pattern could help me to achieve this result and a brief example.

```
window.size(myDom).big();

window.size(myDom).small();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return object with `big` and `small` methods and use closure to access myDom:

```
function size(myDom) {
    return {
        big: () => { myDom.style.... }
        small: () => { .... }
    };
}
```

Or you can create class with `myDom` as constructor parameter (which stores it in the field) and appropriate methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ES6 classes, you could return an instance of a class that wraps around your element:

```
class Sizeable {
    constructor(el) {
        this.el = el;
    }

    big() {
        // do something with this.el
    }

    small() {
        // do something with this.el
    }
}

window.size = function(el) {
    return new Sizeable(el);
};
```

Which is, of course, roughly equivalent to:

```
function Sizeable(el) {
    this.el = el;
}

Sizeable.prototype.big = function() {
    // do something with this.el
}

Sizeable.prototype.small = function() {
    // do something with this.el
}

window.size = function(el) {
    return new Sizeable(el);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `size` method must have *an object* as its return value.

That object must have properties named `big` and `small`.

It should also have any additional data (stored in other properties) that you want to make available to

The values of each of those properties must be *functions*.

Those functions can either read variables from the function which created them (as closures) or use the `this` keyword to read the data from the object (you would need to store the data on that object in other properties).

Comment: could you please provide me an example of code (myDom is a dom element can I add there big/small)? it would really help me. thanks